# How do I select 1 [oldest] row per group of rows, given multiple groups?

Tags: sql

Let's say we have the database table below, called `USER_JOBS`.

[image]

I'd like to write an SQL query that reflects this algorithm:

1. Divide the whole table in groups of rows defined by a common `USER_ID` (in the example table, the 2 resulting groups are colored yellow & green)
2. From each group, select the oldest row (according to `SCHEDULE_TIME`)

From this example table, the desired SQL query would return these 2 rows:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use ranking function (supported in most RDBS):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY SCHEDULE_TIME DESC) AS RowID
    FROM [table]
)
WHERE RowID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH Ranked AS (
        SELECT 
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY ScheduleTime DESC) as Ranking,
            *
        FROM [table_name]
    )

    SELECT Status, Sob_Type, User_ID, TimeStamp FROM ranking WHERE Ranks = 1;
```

Comment: using rank() instead of row_number() could return more than one row per user_id if two oldest records have the same schedule_time

Comment: This is true. I am assuming that his timestamps are using enough precision that this should be virtually impossible, though I yield that there is an opportunity for duplicates. I've awarded gotqn's answer an upvote as such.